# How to change text on a textbox?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a C# script for unity to create dialogue using 'Ink.Runtime' and this procedure in the code is attempting to switch the text to a new line when the condition is met. But I'm not sure how to perform this, dialogueText is the name of the variable I'm trying to change the text for, but how would I declare this variable and define it so I can have it apply the script to the textbox in my code.

Here's the relevant string of code written below

```
private void ContinueStory()
    {
        if (currentStory.canContinue)
        {
            dialogueText.text = currentStory.Continue();
        }
        else
        {
            ExitDialogueMode();
        }
    }
public text dialogueText;
    //what would I write here?
```

I'm relatively new to programming in C# and so help would be much appriciated!

Comment: If you have a dialog in your form you can declare the name in the inspector or properties (don't remember which name) and then change the text by using the name that you gave it. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can find an object by name or tag.  Study these guides:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html